# Python - Loop through log files with some logic

Tags: python

Good Morning,

I have taken on a small project, solely for the purposes of learning python.
So far the script will ssh to another server, to obtain a list of nodes which are down. I want to change this though, to have it store a list of down nodes in a tmp file, and the next day compare one to the other and only work with nodes which are down that weren't down yesterday. But that part can wait...

The issue I'm seeing at the moment is searching for various strings in a number of log files, but if the line count for a particular node exceeds a certain number; rather than being sent to the terminal.. a message is sent instead saying "too many log entries; entries save to /tmp/..

Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't really do what I want.

Also, if you have any other advice for my script, I would be infinitely grateful. I am learning, but it's sinking in slowly! :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#

from subprocess import *
import sys
from glob import glob
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', metavar='logname', help='logfile to check')
args = parser.parse_args()

ssh = Popen(["ssh", "root@srv1", 'check_nodes'],
            shell=False,
            stdout=PIPE,
            stderr=PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()

down_nodes=[]
status_list=["down", "admindown"]

if result == []:
    error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error

else:
        for line in result[1:]:
            columns = line.split()
            status = columns[3]
            nodes = columns[2]
            if status in status_list:
                down_nodes.append(nodes)

if args.f:
    logs = args.f
else:
    try:
        logs = glob("/var/log/*")
    except IndexError:
        print "Something is wrong. Logs not available."
        sys.exit(1)

valid_errors = ["error", "MCE", "CATERR"]

for log in logs:
    with open("log", "r") as tmp_log:
        opn_log = tmp_log.readlines()

for line in open_log:
    for down_nodes in open_log:
        if valid_errors in open_log:
             print valid_errors
```

What I have so far, sort of works in testing.. but it just finds the errors in `valid_errors` and doesn't find lines that have both `down_node` and `valid_errors` in the same time. Also, with a date.. maybe something like, lines in a log that contain `down_node`, `valid_errors` and contains a date string of less than 3 days or something.

As from Friday - I hadn't used Python for anything! I've worked only with shell scripts and always found that a bash script it perfect for what I need. So I am a beginner... :)

Thanks
Jon

Comment: The loop that goes over lines in the file should be nested inside the one that goes over files. Also, your valid_errors is a list, and you are using a wrong syntax to check if any entries are in a line. You can use substr for that. Line is not used, open_log is misspelled. Start small, by finding one entry in a file, and then go from there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. The spelling mistake is because I changed some thing when copy/pasting it into here, changed some srv names etc, and changed the name of variables etc. I'll look up substr and see if I can figure it out. I will need to find lines that contain any error in `valid_errors` as well as any entry in `down_node` and a date.. so I will need to play around a lot it seems.

Comment: Yes, it seems like you've tackled too many new things at once. Break it down in smaller parts and work on those. Feel free to upvote if it helped.

Comment: I have been testing as I go, and I understand everything that I've done so far.. so I don't think I've tackled too much. I was just looking for advice regarding the bit where it scans log files and only reports under a certain number of lines anything more it will add to a tmp file, but I think I will be able to get there my self.. just trying to tap into some of the experience over here :)

Answer (score 0):

I've broken down my specific question if it makes it clearer.. Essentially at the moment, I'm just trying to find a line in a bunch of log files that contains any of the `down_nodes` AND any of the `valid_errors` my code:

```
for node in down_nodes:
    for log in logs:
        with open(log) as log1:
            open_log = log1.readlines()
                for line in open_log:
                    if node + valid_errors in line
                        print line
```

Comment: I hope I'm not thinking along the right lines, because it seems really messy having so many nested conditionals and loops etc..